# Generic wrapper method for AddOrUpdate fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am attempting to write a generic wrapper / extension method for the EF Migrations AddOrUpdate method, however, I receive the following error during design time:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public static void InsertOrUpdate(this Object item, Func<Object, Object> PrimaryKeyMember, DbContext Db, Func<DbContext, DbSet> DbSetAttribute, bool Commit = false)
{
    try
    {
        DbSetAttribute.Invoke(Db).AddOrUpdate(PrimaryKeyMember, item);

        //Commit if required
        if (Commit)
            Db.SaveChanges();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(e.ToString());
        throw;
    }
```

}

I am still new to generics but I can deduce that it's got something to do with the fact that the AddOrUpdate method expects a "Reference Type".  I have also tried the following:

```
public static void InsertOrUpdate<T>(this Object item, Func<Object, Object> PrimaryKeyMember, DbContext Db, Func<DbContext, DbSet<T>> DbSetAttribute, bool Commit = false)
{
    try
    {
        DbSetAttribute.Invoke(Db).AddOrUpdate<T>(PrimaryKeyMember, item);

        //Commit if required
        if (Commit)
            Db.SaveChanges();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(e.ToString());
        throw;
    }
```

}

However, this causes the following error during design time:

> The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter
>   TEntity in the generic type or method
>   blablabla.AddOrUpdate(...).

What am I missing?  I am not sure what a "Reference Type" is...

## Final, working code

I am now using the following code, which utilises one of the overrides for AddOrUpdate:

```
public static void InsertOrUpdate<T>(this T item, Expression<Func<T, object>> IdentifierExpression, DbContext Db, Func<DbContext, IDbSet<T>> DbSetAttribute, bool Commit = false) where T: class
{
    try
    {
        DbSetAttribute.Invoke(Db).AddOrUpdate(IdentifierExpression, item);

        //Commit if required
        if (Commit)
            Db.SaveChanges();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(e.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use the existing framework methods such as `.AddOrUpdate()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520(v=vs.103).aspx ?

Comment: Yes.  I have included `using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;`

Comment: 1. on your screenshot there's an error on AddOrUpdate call but you have provided code for InsertOrUpdate extension method. why? 2. if it was an InsertOrUpdate call, you're missing the third (DbSetAttribute) parameter 3. reference type constraint: void foo<T>(this object o) where T : class {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to wrap this [`DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn176991%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) extension, than I can't understand what `Func<Object, Object> PrimaryKeyMember` means.

Anyway, `AddOrUpdate` is constrained to use classes (== reference types) as entity types. Hence, your wrapper method has to be constrained this way too:

```
public static void InsertOrUpdate<T>(this Object item, Func<Object, Object> PrimaryKeyMember, DbContext Db, Func<DbContext, DbSet<T>> DbSetAttribute, bool Commit = false)
    where T : class
{
     // ...
}
```

**UPD**.

Since you're trying to use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217945%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) overload of `AddOrUpdate`, you should note, that `Func<...>` and `Expression<Func<...>>` are two different types. The first one is a delegate, while the second one is a tree-like representation of code, which could be compiled into delegate with a particular signature.

You must change `PrimaryKeyMember` parameter type from `Func<T, object>` to `Expression<Func<T, object>>`.

Comment: `Func<Object, Object> PrimaryKeyMember` is to basically identify the primary key attribute of item.  Si, usage of this method would be something like: `myEntity.InsertOrUpdate<MyEntityClass>(I => i.Id, Db, dbContext => dbContext.MyEntities, false);`

Comment: Then you need `Func<T, object>`. But how do you plan to use it inside `InsertOrUpdate`? `AddOrUpdate` from EF accepts entity set and entities, there's no need for primary key.

Comment: You are right.  I normally prefer to explicitly state the matching criteria (not always necessarily a PK, can also be something like a name/surname combo or Social security number).  I will post the updated code as I am still getting an error when using `Func<T, object>`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, bud.  I accepted your answer since it addressed my initial question.  I would appreciate if you could help me resolve this last issue though.